# Same Facebook app for multiple (possibly infinite) iOS apps?

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I want to integrate my Facebook app in multiple iOS apps. I know there's a way to include all the bundle IDs in my app settings on Facebook. But the problem is, I am providing this feature in an API.

Any person using my API, should be able make his iOS app connect to my Facebook app. And since the API is public, there is no way I'd know all the possible app ids.

I am using Facebook SDK 3.1 and logging in using

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                              allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to programmatically add Bundle IDs to the Facebook App Dashboard. So unless you know the Bundle IDs ahead of time, you would not be able to set this up.

By the way, you want to be careful about tying one Facebook App ID to apps that are not similar to one another or extensions of one another, ex: a paid vs. free version.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But obviously, theres no way to know the AppIDs of the apps that would be integrating my API. I think I'll have to change my architecture a bit and introduce a server component that would communicate with fb. 

Would like to hear if you have any alternates to that.

Comment: It would help if you provided more context around your API and your set up. For example, would you be able to provide an SDK of your API and have the 3rd party apps get their own Facebook App ID and you set up your own id system to authenticate these apps to use your API?